# Is it possible to kill jQuery UI while it's actively sorting/dragging/etc, so I can inspect the DOM at that point?

Tags: jquery-ui, firebug

I am using jQuery UI sortable and my helper element is doing some funky things in terms of rendering.  Normally I'd just go in with Firebug or other browser dev tools and see what's going on with CSS, DOM, etc.  But there is no way to examine the helper element with dev tools because any such action completes the sortable action and the helper is removed.

Is there a way to "blow up" jQuery UI so it leaves the helper (and placeholders and other jQuery UI DOM elements) in place so that I can examine it?

Answer (score 1):

You can tie into the drag handler option for those plugins and put some code in there and then put a breakpoint on that code.

The drag event happens every time the mouse moves while you are dragging the helper